# How do we say "placed my thumb inside a hose" while inverting the word order of thumb and hose?

Tags: grammar

He placed the hose around his thumb? I can't really think of an idiomatic way of saying it. Is it just me? I am trying to think of a good phrasal verb for this.

Comment: No clear idea what you're looking for here when you say *I am trying to think of a good phrasal verb for this*. Something like *He **blocked** the flow of water **off** with his thumb* ?

Comment: You asked for an idiomatic way to say this. stick x up is a phrasal verb and you haven't seemed to notice that....

Answer (score 1):

> I placed my thumb inside a hose.

To invert it, you would use something like this:

> Inside a hose, I placed my thumb.

Note, however, that even though the syntax works, the inverted sentence is awkward. People would not normally use that phrasing.

It also lends itself to misinterpretation. Even though it wouldn't make sense, it might be thought to mean *when I was inside a hose, I placed my thumb.*

In order to avoid such confusion, a slight change would be required:

> Inside a hose did I place my thumb.

This is less awkward, but it sounds archaic or poetic. That may be fine in the right context, but it's not a natural sentence in general. In short, I don't think there is an idiomatic way of expressing the inversion of the original.

Comment: By hose, I meant a vacuum cleaner hose. Also, can you use a phrasal verb with a preposition like "place around"?

Comment: @JJJJ The meaning that results from the interpretation of a sentence can still not make sense. *I climbed into the vacuum cleaner hose*. The sentence is grammatical, even though it's odd because it doesn't seem to match something that could happen in reality. The fact that the sentence in question might be interpreted as meaning that you are *inside* a vacuum cleaner hose is what makes it problematic.

Answer (score 1):

> I put my thumb inside a hose.

If you invert the action, it becomes

> I placed a hose on my thumb.

Answer (score 1):

**I stuck my thumb up the [vacuum cleaner] hose to clean out a dust ball.**

But there's no inversion, I'm afraid. **stick something up something** [stick one's finger up one's nose]. I can't "feel" the around option at all.

The idiomatic usage here is: to stick something up something; often to describe putting a finger into or up a bodily orifice. Sorry, it can get somewhat gross.

But it can also be totally fine, as well: He stuck his finger in the pie and shoved the piece into his mouth.

Answer (score 0):

You could also say

> His thumb he placed inside the hose.
>
> The hose he placed around his thumb.
>
> The tip of his thumb he placed inside the hose to spray the water farther.
>
> The hose he placed around his thumb, but why we couldn't say.

Comment: By hose, I meant a vacuum cleaner hose. Also, can you use a phrasal verb with a preposition like "place around"?

Comment: @JJJJ: You could say *He placed the vacuum hose **over** his thumb.* or *He put his thumb inside the vacuum hose.*